# Is there a way to make the 'Documents' tab in SharePoint the landing page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365, modern-experience, team-sites

Is it possible to make the 'Documents' section on a SharePoint Team site the landing page?

When you look at my screenshot below you will see the 'Documents' tab which leads to the document library.

[image: SharePoint view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly set the document library page as a default/homepage of SharePoint site.

You can try below workaround for your requirements:

**Workaround**:

1. [Create a new site page in SharePoint site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-use-modern-pages-on-a-sharepoint-site-b3d46deb-27a6-4b1e-87b8-df851e503dec)
2. [Add document library web part on page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-document-library-web-part-a9dfecc3-2050-4528-9f00-2c5afc5731b0) - Add document library web part on page & select default library (Documents/Shared Documents) as source for the web part
3. [Make this newly created page as a home page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-a-different-page-for-your-sharepoint-site-home-page-35a5022c-f84a-455d-985e-c691ab5dfa17)